# Plugins for eclipse to design webpage

Tags: css, jsp, eclipse-plugin, html

I am developing web applications in eclipse kepler using struts2 version.

But to design web page portable tooks a huge time.

I need to know any plugins(WYSWUG) in eclipse to design web page by drag and drop .

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not efficient to develop web page. Rather than Eclipse, I recommend you to use Adobe Dreamweaver CS6. It has very powerful tools to develop web page by dragging and droppping. Also, you can work on only code screen or by splitting code and design window you can see both code and design.

In addition, if you have intermediate or advanced coding knowledge you should prefer code-related IDEs for development. Here's some suggestions:

- PHP: PHPStorm
- C# & ASP.net: VisualStudio
- HTML, Javascript, CSS: Sublime Text 3 or PHPStorm